# Rails 4 - JS Pipeline, put after require_tree

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have `app.js` which depends on around 10 other JS. So I want to put `app.js` last in the order

```
//= require_tree .
//= require app
```

But the way above doesn't work and still list them alphabetically.

I can do this, but not elegant:

```
//= require js_file01
...
//= require js_file10
//= require app
//= require_tree .
```

I can also change `app.js` name into `zzzzz.js` and call it a day. But is there proper way to include it last?

Thanks

Comment: yes, if you want to load things in a given order, you must specify that order.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`require_tree` will require the files in whatever order it feels like. If you want them required in the order you want, then you will need to have many `require` calls.

Alternatively, you could put all those other files into one directory, then `require_tree that_directory` and then `require app` immediately after that.

Comment: Thanks! Requiring the directory is the way to go `require_tree ./priority`